# Child's function doesn't overwrite its parents function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

From my main class, I call the Intro class:

```
package scene {

    public class Intro extends Scene {

        private function _enterScene():void{
            trace(123);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the Scene class:

```
package scene {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Scene extends MovieClip {

        public function Scene() {
            stop();
            _enterScene();
        }

        private function _enterScene():void{
            trace(321);
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason, this traces `321` instead of `123`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: override the function.

Comment: As others already mentioned, use the `override` keyword. Also, it might be worth making `_enterScene()` protected instead of private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the function like:

```
// Intro.as
protected function _enterScene():void {
    trace (123);
}


// Scene.as
override protected function _enterScene():void {
    trace (321);
}
```

Google how classes work and how extending works. There are the basics of OOP.

Comment: I usually program in PHP, so I didn't know about `override` :/ But it's stupid that I used `private` instead of `protected`...